# Ansible task for checking that a host is really offline after shutdown

Tags: ansible, shutdown, ansible-2.x

I am using the following Ansible playbook to shut down a list of remote Ubuntu hosts all at once:

```
- hosts: my_hosts
  become: yes
  remote_user: my_user
  tasks:

    - name: Confirm shutdown
      pause:
        prompt: >-
          Do you really want to shutdown machine(s) "{{play_hosts}}"? Press
          Enter to continue or Ctrl+C, then A, then Enter to abort ...

    - name: Cancel existing shutdown calls
      command: /sbin/shutdown -c
      ignore_errors: yes

    - name: Shutdown machine
      command: /sbin/shutdown -h now
```

Two questions on this:

1. Is there any module available which can handle the shutdown in a more elegant way than having to run two custom commands?
2. Is there any way to check that the machines are really down? Or is it an anti-pattern to check this from the same playbook?

I tried something with the [net_ping module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/net_ping_module.html) but I am not sure if this is its real purpose:

```
- name: Check that machine is down
      become: no
      net_ping:
        dest: "{{ ansible_host }}"
        count: 5
        state: absent
```

This, however, fails with

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "invalid connection specified, expected connection=local, got ssh"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `shutdown` module. You can use single fire-and-forget call:

```
- name: Shutdown server
  become: yes
  shell: sleep 2 && /sbin/shutdown -c && /sbin/shutdown -h now
  async: 1
  poll: 0
```

As for `net_ping`, it is for network appliances such as switches and routers. If you rely on ICMP messages to test shutdown process, you can use something like this:

```
- name: Store actual host to be used with local_action
  set_fact:
    original_host: "{{ ansible_host }}"
- name: Wait for ping loss
  local_action: shell ping -q -c 1 -W 1 {{ original_host }}
  register: res
  retries: 5
  until: ('100.0% packet loss' in res.stdout)
  failed_when: ('100.0% packet loss' not in res.stdout)
  changed_when: no
```

This will wait for `100% packet loss` or fail after 5 retries.
Here you want to use `local_action` because otherwise commands are executed on remote host (which is supposed to be down).
And you want to use trick to store `ansible_host` into temp fact, because `ansible_host` is replaced with `127.0.0.1` when delegated to local host.

Comment: Thank you, that brought me on the right track.
I suggest the following modifications though: 
First: `/sbin/shutdown -c && /sbin/shutdown -h now` will not run the shutdown command if no previous shutdown was scheduled due to the first command then having an exit code of `1` and chaining commands with `&&` -> using `;` instead of `&&` works fine.
Second: (At least on Ubuntu) `ping` returns `100% packet loss`, not `100.0%`.

Comment: Yet another remark, pointed out by my colleague: Waiting for 100% packet loss when running `ping` with only one packet (`-c 1`) and a timeout of one second (`-W 1`) might lead to false positives if there is a network hiccup. Increasing these values a bit might increase reliability.

Comment: Perhaps not in 2018, but today there is a [shutdown module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/shutdown_module.html) - I just don't know whether this will continue only after the actual shutdown itself has completed or simply the command it invoked.

Answer (score 5):

In more restricted environments, where ping messages are blocked you can listen on ssh port until it goes down. In my case I have set timeout to 60 seconds.

```
- name: Save target host IP
  set_fact:
    target_host: "{{ ansible_host }}"

- name: wait for ssh to stop
  wait_for: "port=22 host={{ target_host }} delay=10 state=stopped timeout=60"
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```